# How to switch between Action Actuators

Tags: python, game-engine

I have two action actuators, and I need to switch between the two immediately once a variable has changed.  I have tried multiple things such as logic bricking the set up and using this script:

```
import bge
cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner
sens = cont.sensors['Move']
if sens.positive:
    if own['Y Axis'] == 1:
        cont.activate(cont.actuators['Y Axis'])
        cont.deactivate(cont.actuators['X Axis'])
    else:
        cont.activate(cont.actuators['X Axis'])
        cont.deactivate(cont.actuators['Y Axis'])
```

Where `own['Y Axis']` is the variable that this is dependent on.  It works the first time the variable is switched, and then it doesn't work afterwards.  The actuators, Y Axis and X Axis are Action actuators with the Loop End playback type set.  How can I do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the ***layer*** or ***priority*** of one of the action actuators :

[image]

OR

instead of having two actuators and activating and deactivating the other one, you can use just one and switch the used action :

```
import bge
cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner
sens = cont.sensors['Move']
if sens.positive:
    if own['Y Axis'] == 1:
        cont.actuators['Axis'].action = 'Action1'
        cont.activate(cont.actuators['Axis'])
    else:
        cont.actuators['Axis'].action = 'Action2'
        cont.activate(cont.actuators['Axis'])
```